# Cloned schema object not cloning the permissions for the role my_objectrole

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to clone a schema and the grants on it, but when I try to clone it it will not copy the users or roles on the schema as well, how can I do that?

For example:

USE ROLE ACCOUNTADMIN 
(accountadmin is the owner of Test_db.schema)

```
CREATE Test_DB.SCHEMA_clone 
CLONE Test_DB.SCHEMA
```

I did not see the same grants, so I had to add them after:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA Test_DB.SCHEMA TO ROLE my_objectrole
```

Can I clone and copy the  grant privileges from the cloned object?

Comment: It is not currently possible, but would be a great feature request.  https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cloned object does not retain any granted privileges on the source object itself

[For more info](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/object-clone.html#access-control-privileges-for-cloned-objects)